# Workaround for ambiguous call to overloaded function

Tags: c++

```
void printOutput(std::string text);
void printOutput(std::string& text);
```

Both functions print some text out to the console, but I wanted to handle each case where:

```
std::string testOutput = "asdf";
output->printOutput(testOutput); // Gives the error as it can use either function
```

In some cases I may want to:

```
output->printOutput("asdf"); // Only the first function can be used
```

Rather new to all this, is there a way I can handle this?

Comment: Are the two functions doing different things _besides_ the output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass by const reference:

```
void printOutput(const std::string &text);
```

Both forms can bind to that, and you shouldn't have to modify what you print.

Comment: I think the OP's question asks how to do things the other way round

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev, Oh, handle each differently? I might have misinterpreted it, but it seems like this should be good for printing.

Comment: true. I am not sure I am interpreting the question correctly either, just point out my interpretation.

Comment: I'm not planning to modify, but I was told that passing by reference would avoid creating a copy and pass the actual argument. Sorry if the question was confusing. Was not sure how to word it. I wanted a function or an overload that could deal with a variable argument and just plain "string" as the argument.

Could anyone provide an explanation why using a constant as the parameter solves this or provide a link?

Comment: @Kookehs, A temporary is allowed to bind to a const reference, as it will cause the temporary to live on past when it normally dies. A named object is also allowed to bind to one, just like a non-const reference, but you can't modify it now, which enforces const-correctness. If you ever need to modify it and still don't want a temporary, you can incorporate a move version that takes an rvalue reference.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you're planning to *modify* the string passed in by reference, a single

```
void printOutput(std::string const& text);
```

will work.

Or are you hoping to do something different in each version?